# How to evaluate this line integral

Tags: integration

$$Evaluate \int F.dr $$
where

$$ F = e^x i + xe^{xy} j + xye^{xyz}k$$
 C is the curve

$$ x=t,  y= t^2, z=t^3$$

and $$0 ≤ t ≤ 2$$

I've got

$$ \int_0^2 (e^t + tet^3+t^3e^{t^6}) \cdot (e+e^{2t}+2te^{6t})dt$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_CF(r)\cdot dr &=\int_0^2\left(e^ti+te^{t^3}j+t^3e^{t^6}k\right)\cdot\left(i+2tj+3t^2k\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^2\left(e^t+2t^2e^{t^3}+3t^5e^{t^6}\right)dt\\
&=\left[e^t+\frac{2}{3}e^{t^3}+\frac{1}{2}e^{t^6}\right]\bigg|^{t=2}_{t=0}\\
&=e^2+\frac{2}{3}e^8+\frac{1}{2}e^{64}-\frac{13}{6}
\end{align}